# Unification and implicit cast of the type parameter

Tags: haxe, unification

`class Base`, and `class Ext extends Base`.
`class B<T>` with typed method `foo<T>(value:T)`

Why `B<Base>.foo` doest not accept instance of `B<Ext>` (implicit downcast of the type parameter?) by default?

Here is an example
http://try.haxe.org/#d443f

```
class Test {
    static function main() {

        var bExt = new B(new Ext());
        var bBase = new B(new Base());

        bBase.foo(bExt);
        //ofc 
        //bBase.foo(cast bExt);
    }
}

class B<T>
{
   public function new(v:T)
   {
   }

   public function foo(v:B<T>)
   {
      //  
   }
}

class Base {
    public function new(){}
}
class Ext extends Base {
    public function new(){
        super();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to trigger implicit cast of the type parameter for B.foo?

Comment: Isn't [Haxe manual on variance](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-variance.html) describing precisely this issue?

Comment: Yes, yes it does, stupid me.

Comment: no point in self-critisism, that was an actual question .-. Glad I was of assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to interpret and answer your question:

#### 1. `foo(v:B<T>)`:

This is [your example](http://try.haxe.org/#f70Fc) and it doesn't compile because `T` isn't allowed to be be variant.  It happens because of the very existence of `foo` and because allowing `bBase.foo(bExt)`, that is, unifying `bExt` with `bBase`, will then allow `bBaseOfbExt.foo(bBase)`.

It is the fact that `foo` exists and that it can potentially modify the type that makes the `bExt` unification with `bBase` unsafe; you can see a similar (but maybe clearer) explanation in the manual, using arrays: [type system – variance](http://haxe.org/manual/type-system-variance.html).

#### 2. `foo(v:T)`:

This is closer to what's on the body of your question (but not in the example) and it works [fine](http://try.haxe.org/#1A164).

#### 3. `foo<A>(v:B<A>)`:

Finally, if you have a type parameterized method, it also [works](http://try.haxe.org/#2174D), but you'd probably face other variance issues elsewhere.